# import txt file named words.txt into database

Tags: mysql

I have a text file with a single word per line.  Example:

```
By
the
shore
of
the
ocean
```

I want import them into a sql database called words.sql.

When I try to do it, I get this error:

```
mysql> use words;
Database changed
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/admin/words/words.txt' INTO TABLE words;
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

I launch mysql with this command:

```
mysql -u root -p -D words --local-infile=0
```

What can I do to import this text file into my database?  What am I doing wrong?

I have another text files of famous quotes I want to put into a database called quotes but need to figure out how to tackle this before I go any farther.

Thank you in advance.

(I have gotten these commands from various other websites in case you were wondering how I came about using these commands)

Comment: Try using just `LOAD DATA INFILE`. I hope one of the sites you came across this was the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Yes, and same error.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about which version of MySQL you're using since that seems highly relevant here.

Comment: Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 58
Server version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)